# How to tell Jenkins Android Emulator Plugin to start emulator on a target node?

Tags: jenkins, android-emulator-plugin

I am trying to run an existing emulator using Jenkins Android Emulator Plugin. But it installs / starts an AVD in host (JENKINS_HOME), not the target node (another machine I use for automation related stuff). How to tell the plugin / change its config to create / run the AVDs in target node (connected to jenkins via slave.jar)?

[image: Android Emulator Config]

[image: Target Node Label]

Comment: That works without having to configure anything — the plugin has always been written to work on different build nodes. It's not possible to configure the plugin to create AVDs on the Jenkins master. What kind of build agent are you trying to run the build on, and are you sure that's where your freestyle build that includes the Android Emulator step is running?

Comment: When I try to run this, Jenkins cannot find the AVD I created in the target Node. I have updated the question to show my configs. Instead the plugin try installing Android Sdk in the Jenkins Home. I cancel the job at that point.

And you probably don't understand my question. Jenkins master can be your own localhost when you didn't specify any target node. Your following statement is wrong "It's not possible to configure the plugin to create AVDs on the Jenkins master."

Comment: You can't configure the plugin to create AVDs on the master. But if your build agent happens to be the master node (which is a bad practice), then AVDs will be created there. I just meant that there isn't a way to disable the plugin from working on the assigned build agent. What does the console output of your build look like?